# Respond to events from a list of class instances

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, events, event-handling

I have a .NET class, InstrumentConnector, that has an event, StatusChanged.  I want to create several instances of this class (each class handles a separate file) and respond when the StatusChanged event is raised any instance.  How would I do this in .NET?  Do I want to create a List(Of InstrumentConnector) or a similar IEnumerable?  How do I write the event handler to respond to a particular instance's StatusChanged event?

Here is the InstrumentConnector class and the module with the StatusChanged handler:

```
Public Class InstrumentConnector

Private _inProcessDir As String
Private _doneDir As String

Private _dataFileName As String
Public ReadOnly Property DataFileName() As String
    Get
        Return _dataFileName
    End Get

End Property


Private WithEvents _processTimer As Timers.Timer

Private _fileStatus As Status
Public ReadOnly Property FileStatus() As Status
    Get
        Return _fileStatus
    End Get

End Property


Public Sub New(ByVal inProcessDirectory As String, ByVal doneDirectory As String)
    _inProcessDir = inProcessDirectory
    _doneDir = doneDirectory
    _fileStatus = Status.Waiting
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal inProcessDirectory As String)
    Me.New(inProcessDirectory, IO.Path.Combine(inProcessDirectory, "done"))
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeTimer()
    _processTimer = New Timers.Timer
    With _processTimer
        .Interval = 1000
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub Process(ByVal dataFileName As String)

    _dataFileName = IO.Path.GetFileName(dataFileName)

    InitializeTimer()

    _processTimer.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub _processTimer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles _processTimer.Elapsed

    '1. Look for file in Done directory
    '2. Evaluate its approval status
    '3. If not completed change approval setting in file and move to InProcess directory

    If IsFileInProcessDirectory() = True Then
        MoveFileToDoneDirectory()
    Else
        If IsFileInDoneDirectory() = True Then
            If IsFileApproved() = True Then
                _fileStatus = Status.Accepted
                RaiseEvent StatusChanged(Nothing)
            Else
                If NeedsSecondAttempt() = True Then
                    MoveFileToProcessDirectory()
                Else
                    _fileStatus = Status.Rejected
                    RaiseEvent StatusChanged(Nothing)
                End If

            End If

        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub MoveFileToDoneDirectory()

    Dim fileContents As String
    fileContents = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(IO.Path.Combine(_inProcessDir, _dataFileName))

    If GetFileApprovalStatus() = True Then
        fileContents = String.Concat("9999", fileContents.Substring(4))
    End If

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(IO.Path.Combine(_doneDir, _dataFileName), fileContents, False)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(IO.Path.Combine(_inProcessDir, _dataFileName))

End Sub

Private Function NeedsSecondAttempt() As Boolean
    Dim fileContents As String
    fileContents = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(IO.Path.Combine(_doneDir, _dataFileName))

    If fileContents.StartsWith("9999") And fileContents.Substring(111, 1) = "1" Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If

End Function

Private Sub MoveFileToProcessDirectory()

    Dim fileContents As String
    fileContents = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(IO.Path.Combine(_doneDir, _dataFileName))

    fileContents = fileContents.Remove(111, 1).Insert(111, "1")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(IO.Path.Combine(_doneDir, _dataFileName), fileContents, False)

    My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(IO.Path.Combine(_doneDir, _dataFileName), IO.Path.Combine(_inProcessDir, _dataFileName))

End Sub

Private Function IsFileInDoneDirectory() As Boolean

    Dim fileExists As Boolean
    fileExists = My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(IO.Path.Combine(_doneDir, _dataFileName))

    Return fileExists

End Function

Private Function IsFileInProcessDirectory() As Boolean

    Dim fileExists As Boolean
    fileExists = My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(IO.Path.Combine(_inProcessDir, _dataFileName))

    Return fileExists

End Function

Private Function IsFileApproved() As Boolean

    Dim fileContents As String
    fileContents = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(IO.Path.Combine(_doneDir, _dataFileName))

    If fileContents.Substring(0, 4) = "9999" Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If

End Function

Private Function GetFileApprovalStatus() As Boolean

    Dim randNum As New Random
    Dim nextNum = randNum.Next(1, 10)

    '60% of all samples will be approved
    If nextNum > 6 Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If

End Function

Public Event StatusChanged(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

Protected Overridable Sub OnStatusChanged(ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.StatusChanged
    _processTimer.Stop()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    MyBase.Finalize()
    _processTimer.Stop()

End Sub

Public Enum Status
    Accepted
    Rejected
    Waiting
End Enum
```

End Class

```
Module Module1

Private WithEvents detector As NewFileDetector
Private WithEvents newIC As InstrumentConnector
Private ICList As New List(Of InstrumentConnector)
Private fileDirectory As String

Sub Main()

    fileDirectory = "c:\temp\inproc"

    Console.WriteLine("Mock IC program running...")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to quit...")

    detector = New NewFileDetector(fileDirectory)


    Dim keyresponse As ConsoleKeyInfo = Nothing

    Do
        keyresponse = Console.ReadKey

    Loop Until keyresponse.Key = ConsoleKey.Escape 'Quit program on ESC

End Sub

Private Sub detector_FilesFound(ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles detector.FilesFound

    Console.WriteLine("Files found: {0}", detector.FileList.Count)

    For Each filename In detector.FileList
        newIC = New InstrumentConnector(fileDirectory)
        ICList.Add(newIC)
        newIC.Process(filename)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub newIC_StatusChanged(ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles newIC.StatusChanged
    Console.WriteLine("File: {0} Status: {1}", newIC.DataFileName, newIC.FileStatus.ToString)
    ICList.Remove(newIC)

End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you store the InstrumentConnectors is not related t the events. A `List(Of T)` is fine.

And you can hook up a listener class to multiple sources of events. That is why the standard pattern in .NET has the `sender` parameter. Just cast that to an InstrumentConnector and you're done.

That is, as long as StatusChanged is designed according to the rules.

---

#### OK, Take 2.

There is way too much code now. Hard to get through.

```
   Public Event StatusChanged(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
```

Is not defined properly. It should have been

```
   Public Event StatusChanged(ByVal sender as Object,  ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
```

And, my VB is a bit rusty, next to the "Handles " notation you should be able to put a statement (somewhere)

```
 HandlesEvent Me.StatusChangedHandler, someInstrument.Statuschanged  ' very sloppy approx
```

And then in a class of your choice (the Form maybe)

```
 Sub StatusChangedHandler(ByVal sender as Object,  ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim InsConn as InstrumentConnector = sender ' may need a CType() here
    .... 
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Henk.  Can you provide an example of how to hook up a listener class and cast it to the InstrumentConnector class?

Comment: I edited the question to include the InstrumentConnector class and the controlling module.  Let me know if you need more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late on this, but:  this is exactly the problem Microsoft's CAB framework solves.  It allows any event to have multiple subscribers *and* multiple publishers.

There is an open-source version of this framework available [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/EventBroker.aspx).